# How to use Android controls in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to create Xamarin form which has an Android rating bar and iOS slider.
Below is the XAML file I am using.
I can see the Label but not able to see the rating bar when I try to run in Android device. 
Please help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:UIKit;assembly=Xamarin.iOS;targetPlatform=iOS"
             xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Android.Widget;assembly=Mono.Android;targetPlatform=Android"
             xmlns:androidForms="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;targetPlatform=Android"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="XamrineTest.Page1">
    <StackLayout  BackgroundColor="Green" >
        <Label Text="Welcome to Page1!" BackgroundColor="Gray"/>
            <ios:UIDatePicker />
            <ios:UISlider MaxValue="10" Value="{Binding SlideValue}" />
            <ios:UIStepper />
            <ios:UISwitch />
        <android:RatingBar BackgroundColor="Lavender" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                                Scale="0.4" 
                                    StarCount="5" Step="0.5" Margin="0" SelectedColor="Orange"
                                                   HeightRequest="40" UnSelectedColor="LightGray" Rate="{Binding Rating,Mode=TwoWay}">

        </android:RatingBar>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are several problem in your code:

1.the namespace you used is not right, just change to this:

```
 <androidWidget:RatingBar x:Arguments="{x:Static androidLocal:MainActivity.Instance}" >
 </androidWidget:RatingBar>
```

And using following namespacing:

```
xmlns:androidWidget="clr-namespace:Android.Widget;assembly=Mono.Android;targetPlatform=Android"
```

2.we also need the following code to init `androidWidget:RatingBar`

```
   x:Arguments="{x:Static androidLocal:MainActivity.Instance}"
```

define the `Instance` in `MainActivity` of android code:

```
 public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    internal static MainActivity Instance { get; private set; }  // define Instance 

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        Instance = this;// init Instance 
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
}
```

For more details, you can check:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-views/xaml

And this link also includes some  useful samples, you can refer to it.

**Update:**

Yes, you can also use `x:Arguments="{x:Static androidForms:Forms.Context}"`,
and the following code  works properly.

```
<android:RatingBar x:Arguments="{x:Static androidForms:Forms.Context}" NumStars="5" StepSize="1.0"  Rating="{Binding Rating,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

**Note:**

The properties as follows you used in RatingBar does not exist.

```
BackgroundColor="Lavender" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                            Scale="0.4" 
                                StarCount="5" Step="0.5" Margin="0" SelectedColor="Orange"
                                               HeightRequest="40" UnSelectedColor="LightGray" Rate="{Binding Rating,Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Comment: Thank you this helps a lot. I also need to add :     [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Skip)]
 so that my controls appear in emulator.

Comment: However i am not able to manage the count of the stars. Also this works :  x:Arguments="{x:Static androidForms:Forms.Context}" but not this :    x:Arguments="{x:Static androidLocal:MainActivity.Instance}"

Comment: Thank you very much